# how to remove app name from http://localhost/website/app/controller/action in redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes

i have contact us page in cakephp and i have use

http://localhost/parcel3/contact-us

for call contact-us page and in this page i have sent a email and setFlash message and redirect on the contact-us page but after redirect my url converted into

http://localhost/parcel3/app/contact-us

but i need http://localhost/parcel3/contact-us, i changed route file for not display 'app' in url but when page redirect it is display how to change it.

Comment: Can you put up the code for your $this->redirect()

Comment: What is your DocumentRoot set to in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

how do you redirect?
with an array url? or string url?
i bet the latter... please post your redirect code.

PS: i strongly advice you to use vhosts:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/

it makes your life easier and simulates the location of your live server. no redirecting problems anymore plus some other advantages.

Comment: $this->redirect(array('action' => 'contact-us'));